# K&R Exercise 1-19: Reverse Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, terminate

I'm able to reverse the array fine, but I can't get the program to terminate when I do CTRL+D(EOF) in terminal.
The only way I can get the program to terminate is if the very first thing I do after compiling is doing CTRL+D.  But if I type in one string, then CTRL+D will not work after that.

I'm not quite sure where my error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 // Maximum input.

// ----------------- reverseLine -----------------
// This method reads in chars to be put into an
// array to make a string. EOF and \n are the
// delimiters on the chars, then \0 is the
// delimiter for the string itself. Then the
// array is swapped in place to give the reverse
// of the string.
//------------------------------------------------
int reverseLine(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i, newL;
  // c is the individual chars, and i is for indices of the array.
  for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
    s[i] = c;
    }

  if (c == '\n') // This lets me know if the text ended in a new line.
    {
      newL = 1;
    }

  // REVERSE
  int toSwap;
  int end = i-1;
  int begin = 0;
  while(begin <= end) // Swap the array in place starting from both ends.
    {
      toSwap = s[begin];
      s[begin] = s[end];
      s[end] = toSwap;

      --end;
      ++begin;
    }

  if (newL == 1) // Add the new line if it's there.
    {
      s[i] = '\n';
      ++i;
    }

  s[i] = '\0'; // Terminate the string.  

  return i;
}

int main()
{
  int len;
  char line[MAXLINE];

  while ((len = reverseLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)  // If len is  zero, then there is no line to recored.
    {
      printf("%s", line);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The only thing I can think of is the while loop in main checks if len > 0, so if I type EOF, maybe it can't make a valid comparison?  But that wouldn't make sense as to why it works when that's the first and only thing I type.

Comment: You aren't running your program on Windows, are you?

Comment: @user3121023 you're right, it was as simple as that.  I'm embarrassed that I didn't try doing it a few times.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't initialize `newL`, so if your read loop doesn't terminate with a newline character, your program exhibits undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will never read the EOF because of this condition:

```
(c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';
```

As soon as c is equal to '\n' the loop terminates and all the following characters are ignored. I think you should separate input from line reversing and make the usual checks on the reverse function parameters.

```
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define SIZE_MAX (256U)

 static bool linereverse(char *line);
 static bool deletenewline(char *s);

 int main(void)
 {
       char buff[SIZE_MAX];
       bool success;
       (void) fputs("Enter a string: ", stdout);
       if( NULL == fgets(buff,(size_t) SIZE_MAX, stdin))
       {
            (void) fputs("Error: invalid input!\n",stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       success = deletenewline(buff);
       if(false == success)
       {
             (void) fputs("Error: cannot remove newline\n",stderr);
             return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       success = linereverse(buff);
       if(false == success)
       {
            (void) fputs("Error: cannot reverse the line");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
      (void) fputs("The line reversed is: ", stdout);
      (void) fputs(buff, stdout);
      (void) puchar('\n');
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
 static bool linereverse(char *line)
 {
      size_t i;
      size_t j;
      char tmp;
      if(NULL == line)
      {
           return false;
      }
      i = 0;
      j = strlen(line) - 1;
     while(i < j)
     {
         tmp = line[i];
        line[i] = line[j];
        line[j] tmp;
        ++i;
         --j;
     }
     return true;
 }
static bool deletenewline(char *s)
{
     char *p;
     if(NULL == s)
     {
         return false;
     }
     p = strrchr(s,'\n');
     if(NULL != p)
     {
         *p = '\0';
     }
     return true;
}
```